# Collections .sort works but collections .reverse doesn't for me

Tags: java, sorting, reverse

I am trying to sort and reverse and a list of lines. I got collections.sort to work but not collections.reverse and i don't know why.

**Works**

```
public List<String> descending()
{
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>(10);
Collections.sort(oneName, new OneNameCountCompare());
for(OneName b: oneName)
{
    x.add(b.toString());
    if (x.size() == 10) // Or don't use enhanced for, use an index instead
    {
        break;
    }
}
return x;
```

**Doesn't Work**

error: method reverse in class Collections cannot be applied to given types;

Collections.reverse(oneName, new OneNameCountCompare());
               ^
 required: List

found: ArrayList,OneNameCountCompare

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
public List<String> ascending()
{
List<String> y = new ArrayList<String>(10);
Collections.reverse(oneName, new OneNameCountCompare());
for(OneName c: oneName)
{
    y.add(c.toString());
    if (y.size() == 10) // Or don't use enhanced for, use an index instead
    {
        break;
    }
}
return y;
}
```

Comment: [Collections.reverse(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) doesn't take a comparator. Also, what do you mean does not work?

Comment: Maybe study the Javadoc or listen to your IDE's proposals.

Comment: `reverse` is for reversing elements in list, not for sorting in descending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collections.reverse( )` only accept `List<E>` as its argument !

So use the following logic :

```
Collections.sort(oneName, Collections.reverseOrder(new OneNameCountCompare()));
```

Comment: ... or implement this logic inside your comparator.